# twig syntax in for loop using sub array $array[$index] as 'in' clause

Tags: for-loop, twig

this part of code comes from a classic view

```
<?php foreach($bookmarks as $bookmark): ?>
[...]
<?php foreach($tags[$bookmark->id] as $tag): ?>
```

I want to transpose it in a twig view

Know how to write first phrase :
`{% for bookmark in bookmarks %}` 
But fail for the second one

`{% for tag in tags[ bookmark.id ] %}`

expected to use a sub array as array in "in" clause of "for" tag
Get an error Unsupported operand types: string / null
It seems to be a simple problem of syntax, but can't find doc about it, can someone leed me to doc or solution?
Thanks/Merci
Eric

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/yjs2e5)

Comment: Are you sure that for every bookmark you have a collection of tags? According to the error this isn't the case. Switch your code to `{% for tag in tags[bookmark.id]|default([]) %}` to catch the cases where your bookmark doesn't have any tags associated to it

Comment: Yes i was shure to have a collection of tags. But your question helped me to verify content of array tags, so i slightly modified the way i load it and now it works. Thanks!